# Volley-AuthFailureError

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am trying to insert new user in phpMyAdmin database when users populate textboxes on android device. For that i write php code and I test it on POSTMAN and it's works but when i test on android real device i got AuthFailureError! In POSTMAN i set Authorization to "No Auth". 
This is my code in android studio:

```
public class Registration extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText name,surname,email,password,adress;
    private  Button btnLog;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private  static  final String URL="http://192.168.*.*/Log/LogUser.php";
    private StringRequest request;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registruj_se);
        name=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        surname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtSurname);
        email=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
        password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);
        adress=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtAdress);
       btnLog=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLog);
        requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        btnLog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                request=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,URL,new Response.Listener<String>(){
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try
                        {
                            JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
                        if(jsonObject.names().get(0).equals("success")){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"success:"+jsonObject.getString("success"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Welcome.class));
                        }else{  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"error:"+jsonObject.getString("error"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}

                        }

                        catch (JSONException e){e.printStackTrace();}
                    }
                },new Response.ErrorListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


                        if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Cannot connect to Internet...Please check your connection!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"The server could not be found. Please try again after some time!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"AuthFailureError",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Parsing error! Please try again after some time!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        } else if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"NoConnectionError",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Connection TimeOut! Please check your internet connection.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    }
                })
                {

                   @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        HashMap<String,String>hashMap=new HashMap<String, String>();
                        hashMap.put("name",name.getText().toString());
                        hashMap.put("surname",surname.getText().toString());
                        hashMap.put("email",email.getText().toString());
                        hashMap.put("password",password.getText().toString());
                        hashMap.put("adress",adress.getText().toString());
                        return  hashMap;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        // do not add anything here
                        return headers;
                    }
                    @Override
                    public String getBodyContentType() {
                        return "application/json";
                    }

                };
                requestQueue.add(request);
            }
        });
```

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

In `getBodyContentType()` method return `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` instead of `"application/json"`

**Code**

```
@Override
public String getBodyContentType() {
       return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
}
```

Comment: This seems like a guess... Not sure why that would affect a AuthFailure

Comment: Thanks for reply! I solve my problem. So anyone who test application on real device its important to type ip adress of your computer in browser of your mobile device and if you see something like "forbidden you don't have permission to access / on this server"-go to wamp server and click on apache->httpd.conf and find Denied from all,and replace with Allow from ip adress of your mobile phone,and after that restart in wamp all services.