# Can't add Volley parameter

Tags: android

I can't get it done...

I need to download json with Volley library, and I need to put inside header and body in POST parameter:

```
usr = "example@ciao.com";
pwd = "123Prova!";

String url = "http://localhost:8080/...";

RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

        Log.i("VOLLEY", response.toString());
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        Log.e("VOLLEY", error.toString());
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "qualche errore", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}){
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>(); 
        params.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        params.put("wellu-client-id", "a056fe5c-1dac-4c12-8b57-8189e45c0b58");

        return params;
    }
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>(); 
        params.put("email", usr);
        params.put("password", pwd);

        return params;
    }
};
Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext()).add(jsonRequest);
```

this parameter work in Postman chrome app... but here brings me in `.ErrorListener()` and I really don't know why.

Comment: and the error logged inside the `ErrorListener.onErrorResponse` is ...?

Comment: Try using `StringRequest` instead of `JsonObjectRequest` then you will change the string back to json  Object in response. If that doesnt work trying to use a smaller context instead of getApplicationContext

Comment: hi Xenolion... nothing i am in error

Comment: @pleft  error is: [com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:8080]......... i have uses-permission INTERNET and with Postman function! ufff

Comment: @francescofreddi Are you running that server on the Android device? If not, localhost (or 127.0.0.1) is not going to work

Answer (score 0):

You should put the address (IP) of your server not localhost (localhost in an android device is itself, not the server)

```
String url = "http://localhost:8080/...";
```

So change the `localhost` part to the `ip` address of your server and make sure the server and the android device are connected to the same network.

Comment: i change in String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/etc..... but make me error: [10-25 12:58:02.236 11215-11477/francyfre.com.trylogin E/Volley: [394] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for http://10.0.2.2:8080/wellu/auth
10-25 12:58:02.239 11215-11215/francyfre.com.trylogin E/VOLLEY: com.android.volley.ServerError]..... i dont know what is problem now

Comment: i have Unexpected response code 400 and com.android.volley.ServerError   :(

Comment: probably i need to give JSONObject instead of null in JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() { ??

Comment: Why don't you change your `Log.e("VOLLEY", error.toString());` to something more useful like `Log.e("VOLLEY", "error response", error);` and post **all** the stacktrace not just some part.

Comment: error -> error response: 
                                                              com.android.volley.AuthFailureError
                                                                  at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:159)
                                                                  at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)

Comment: @francescofreddi https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44987087/volley-authfailureerror/44999625#comment76975899_44999625

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively overriding the function 
`public byte[] getBody()` to send data.But you must be change your backend codes